# Twilio checking character as input

Tags: twilio, chatbot, twilio-studio

In twilio studio,I was trying to build a flow, which will check if customer replied with words or not,flow check if the reply contains name or not.after adding spilt based on , I didnt find the correct widget to check this, whats the way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the the documentation for the `Split Based on Widget`

[Split Based On...](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/split-based-on)

Reference: "Here are some usage examples of other conditions:"